# Images not loading from firebase storage url

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I have some images loaded in my Firebase Storage but when I try to create a simple html with their url, the images don't load (I'm using Chrome):

```html
<html>
<img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-storage-imgs.appspot.com/o/generalPhotos_0.png?alt=media&token=e8d2280b-6bd2-423c-b66e-6e87147702c2"
    alt="test">
<img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-storage-imgs.appspot.com/o/generalPhotos_1.png?alt=media&token=7c4236b3-8776-4f90-9c79-30557ad01e9d"
    alt="test">
<img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/test-storage-imgs.appspot.com/o/generalPhotos_2.png?alt=media&token=0be54d2d-68f7-4ac0-bd7c-0b524f9e8b5f"
    alt="test">
</html>
```

The permissions are ok:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

I've got the urls directly from the Storage web interface, clicking on the image file and copying the link from "name".

If I load an image in a browser, the image is downloaded to my computer.

The file is not readable when downloading an image with `curl` (looks like it is corrupted).

The HTTP response looks good (status 200):

[image]

Comment: Security rules don't affect the way download URLs work at all.  Please answer a few questions: How did you generate those URLs?  What happens if you load an image URL directly into your browser, not by embedding a page?  What happens if you use curl to access them? We need to look at the result of the HTTP request to understand what's happening.  Please edit the question to share more details.

Comment: The URLs in your question load fine when I put them in the address bar of my browser. My guess is that you're having some sort of CORS errors, so you'll want to check https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-storage%5D+cors